# In JAVA how to check for multiple number in two ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Trying to check if a number is binary or not - so User will type an integer & will validate if that is binary or not. My code is as below & it is always returning False so the if statement is not working - also tried to convert to string but getting the same result - Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int aa = 5101012;

ArrayList dd = new ArrayList();

while(aa>0){
    dd.add(aa%10);
    aa = aa/10;}

ArrayList dd1 = new ArrayList();

dd1.add(2);
dd1.add(3);
dd1.add(4);
dd1.add(5);
dd1.add(6);
dd1.add(7);
dd1.add(8);
dd1.add(9);

System.out.println(dd1.contains(dd));}}
```

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate 10base2 from 10base10?  Because if the value is entered by the user, without any other information, there is no way to know unless you can read their mind.

Comment: Why do you try to see if an object of type ArrayList is contained in an ArrayList of integers. That will always return false. contains method checks to see if the object received as parameter is equal to any object form the ArrayList.

Comment: @Onu check out my answer I gave you 2 ways you could do it one using what you already have and one (a lot shorter) using regex...

Answer (score 0):

***************************REGEX SHORT VERSION*********************************************************
If you want to shorten your code you could use regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int aa = 10101;
    String test = "" + aa;
    System.out.println("" + !test.matches(".*[23456789].*"));

}
```

This will return `true` for `10101` and `false` for `5101012`.

************************************LONG VERSION*********************************************************
You should check each element individually if you want to see which digits are binary and which ones aren't:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int aa = 5101012;

    ArrayList<Integer> dd = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(aa>0){
        dd.add(aa%10);
        aa = aa/10;}

    ArrayList<Integer> dd1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    dd1.add(2);
    dd1.add(3);
    dd1.add(4);
    dd1.add(5);
    dd1.add(6);
    dd1.add(7);
    dd1.add(8);
    dd1.add(9);

    for(Integer a : dd)
    {
        System.out.println(dd1.contains(a));
    }
}
```

You were trying to see if dd1 contains an arraylist of objects which it doesn't it contains objects(`Integer`) individually.

Comment: Hi brso05 - I am self learning JAVA & trying developing my skill by doing different exercise - from your both code learned a lot. Appreciated your quick & elaborate response

Comment: Hi brso05 - I am so loving your REGEX SHORT VERSION - can please explain the code a little or can you refer any site from where I can learn those magic trick - Thanks

Comment: @Onu Regex can be used to match patterns in a string.  Basically this regex says `.*` which means anything(any characters) followed by 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 followed by `.*` anything(any characters).  All you have to do is use `matches` with this regex...If it matches this pattern then the number is not binary it contains a number that is not 1 or 0 `return false` if it doesn't match this pattern then you assume it is binary contains only 1's and 0's `return true`.

Answer (score 0):

One way (not the most elegant) is to convert it to string and then do:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
if ( string.charAt(i) != '1' && string.charAt(i) != '0') {
System.out.println("Not a binary number!");
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi iullianr - Thanks for prompt answer, that was  my first try - converting int to string but that didn't work - now I can see why, because I kind of messed up on if clause, now it works - thanks again.